# Monitor nonPagedPool (Memory) in Java

Tags: java, memory

Is there a way to monitor the nonPagedPool-Area of the memory in Java?
The only [library](https://github.com/jezhumble/javasysmon/wiki) that I've found can only read the total amount of memory in use but not this specific area of memory.

Comment: Do you mean this? http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/03/26/3211216.aspx Non paged pool is only used by the kernel and drivers on windows and is not accessible to Java.  You need to find a command line tool to tell you this.

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean. The reason I would like to monitor the nonPagedPool is because of a memory-leak that occurs in this area when I am using a certain program. I already wrote a powershell-script that is able to do that.  Now I would like to implement this in a tool with a GUI.

Comment: You can write a Java program with a GUI which call command line or JNA calls to give you the information you need.  As this is entirely system dependent, you need to find out how to do this for windows from any environment and then you can call this from Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) and call [PSAPI.GetPerformanceInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683210(v=vs.85).aspx) to solve the problem. Calling commandline might be to expensive and pretty ugly also because I need to check the running processes and nonPagedPool every second.
Luckily its not that hard to implement this with JNA:

**Main-Class:**

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class JNA_PSAPI_Test_optimized {

    public static native boolean GetPerformanceInfo(PerformanceInformationStruct pPerformanceInformation, int cb);

    static {
        Native.register("psapi");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        PerformanceInformationStruct tPerfInfo = new PerformanceInformationStruct();

        while (true){
            GetPerformanceInfo(tPerfInfo, 104);
            System.out.println("nonPagedPool (MB): "+tPerfInfo.KernelNonpaged * tPerfInfo.PageSize / Math.pow(1024,2));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

**Struct-Class:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;

public class PerformanceInformationStruct extends Structure {
    public int cb;
    public long CommitTotal;
    public long CommitLimit;
    public long CommitPeak;
    public long PhysicalTotal;
    public long PhysicalAvailable;
    public long SystemCache;
    public long KernelTotal;
    public long KernelPaged;
    public long KernelNonpaged;
    public long PageSize;
    public int HandleCount;
    public int ProcessCount;
    public int ThreadCount;
    public PerformanceInformationStruct() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"cb", "CommitTotal", "CommitLimit", "CommitPeak", "PhysicalTotal", "PhysicalAvailable", "SystemCache", "KernelTotal", "KernelPaged", "KernelNonpaged", "PageSize", "HandleCount", "ProcessCount", "ThreadCount"});
    }
}
```